# Why am I getting errors thrown on PHP code wrapped in a try-catch?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

```
<?php

try {   
    $attrs = $xml->attributes();
    $code = $attrs['_Code'];
}
catch (Exception $e)  
{
    $code = '';
}

?>
```

Gets me:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object on
>   line 6

Why am I getting errors thrown on code wrapped in a try-catch??

---

**NOTE:** It *is* possible to avoid this error by using the following code. (The question is not about avoiding the error, but why it's not being caught- still I thought I'd share the non-erroring code anyway)

```
if (is_object($xml) && method_exists($xml,'attributes')) {
    $attrs = $xml->attributes();
    $code = !empty($attrs['_Code'])?$attrs['_Code']:'';
 }
else {
    $code = '';
}
```

Comment: Please post where $xml comes from, it should be something like: $xml = new classname;

Comment: Not the question- im not trying to get the $xml right, im trying to handle the error

Comment: Can you not implement a method_exists() or is_callable() test?

Comment: Scuzzy- please refer to the last line of the question- it's not why an error is happening, it's why i can't *catch* it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP fatal errors cannot be caught. I don't know the specifics of what you're doing, but you'll have to figure out some other way to test whether `$xml->attributes()` will work or not.

Also, swallowing every error and not logging it anywhere is bad practice because when stuff starts breaking you won't have any idea of why.

Comment: It is a bit tricky to say that "fatal errors" cannot be caught.  In principle it makes sense, but an uncaught exception is a fatal error.  Would you say that can be caught?

Answer (score 0):

`try`/`catch` only works for *exceptions*, not parse errors.  You have to test to make sure that `$xml` has an `attributes` method to avoid such an error (could be called a null pointer, but not exactly).

Comment: This isn't a parse error by any stretch of the definition. This is a runtime error.

Comment: @Patrick php is interpreted .. parsing and running are one and the same :)

Comment: @Yarin we are both right.  The point is you cannot use `try`/`catch` to suppress this error.

Comment: @tandu: No, if it were a parse error it would look like this: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' in - on line 2". PHP explicitly separates parse errors, which are referred to using E_PARSE, from run-time fatal errors, which are E_ERROR.